# Request additional claims Owin Security

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, owin

I am trying to retrieve additional information from a google OAuth handshake using OWIN Security.

I have the following to request the user profile claim from Google and the google permissions page reflects that this claim is requested.

```
var googleConfig = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = ClientId",
    ClientSecret = "Secret"
};

googleConfig.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleConfig);
```

However when i get the response back using `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` there is only one name claim on the user.

What do i need to do to get back the user profile data from google on login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the additional claims in the Provider's OnAuthenticate event. In there the context param contains these additional properties you asked for in the scopes. For exmaple, when using Facebook:

```
var fb = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "...",
    AppSecret = "...",
    AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.User["birthday"] != null)
            {
                ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, ctx.User["birthday"].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
};
fb.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fb);
```

Comment: Hey this looks exactly right but the claims still don't get propagated onto the user token. I can see them inside the OnAuthenticated method but further on in the request they don't exist. It looks like the identity on the authentication context is not the same as the one on the user object

Comment: Then the issue might be somewhere in the MVC sample code that transitions from the external cookie to the application cookie. I don't know what that code looks like in your project.

Comment: I found your primer blog post (http://brockallen.com/2014/01/09/a-primer-on-external-login-providers-social-logins-with-owinkatana-authentication-middleware/ thanks its good) what i needed was `Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie").Result`